# Build WPF Application - Application Name

Tags: wpf

While building WPF application, `Msbuild.exe` looks at the starting page's title present in XAML and uses that as the application name. I was wondering if we can customize this application name during the build process. I tried with property name `applicationname` in the command line and it didn't work. Are there any ways to do it in command line (through `Msbuild.exe`), Visual Studio IDE or through makefile?

Here is what is failing in renaming the application. It is picking up "MainWindow" name from the title property of the example application's `mainwindow.xaml`.

```
msbuild.exe -t:Rebuild -p:Configuration=Release -p:appname=exampleapp -p:AssemblyProduct=exampleapp -p:AssemblyName=exampleapp example.sln
```

Comment: Are you talking about the EXE filename that is built? If so, you can change it in Visual Studio by right-clicking on the project file, selecting Properties and changing the Assembly name in the Application tab.

Comment: Assembly name  works! I was able get the name assembly exe to what I want. What I need is when I run the exe, on windows task bar to reflect the running app name to be that of what I had customize to. I was thinking that would parameter appname. But it does not seem to work, as the build takes this value from what is set in the xaml's title property. Thanks for replying.